# Form inputs have no cursor - jQuery UI in Chrome after htaccess login

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, jquery-ui

I have an HTML5 form that has always worked as expected. It is accessed via SSL, and I have a simple .htaccess password on the directory. This still works as expected in FF.

In Chrome, once the user logs in via .htaccess, the form displays normally. However, there are no input cursors, even when the user clicks on an input field. This is disorienting for the user! Of note:

1. If the user types anyway, it does accept input (but the user freaks out).
2. If the user clicks on another tab and then returns, the form fields function correctly.
3. This affects text, jQuery UI autocomplete, and password fields.
4. The HTML seems to validate @W3C.
5. Even stripped of all local stylesheets and JS (loading only jQuery + jQuery UI), this is observed.
6. Once the user logs in via .htaccess, behavior is normal for the rest of the session, but presents again whenever the browser is restarted.
7. This all used to work fine in Chrome, it recently (apx. 2-3 months) stopped.

I can't do a fiddle, because the issue only presents when the .htaccess login dialog shows. Here is a super simple form with one text input that still displays the issue (when in a directory protected by .htaccess):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">          
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
     <title>Main</title>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="priv" method="post" action="DisplayMainPriv.php" target="_blank" >
<div id="priv" class="text">         
  <label for="pass">
     Run Privileged Reports<br><br>
     Pass: 
  </label><br>
     <input type="text" name="pass" id="pass" >    
     <input type="submit" name="priv-submit" value="Go" >
</div>

</form>                   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think any `.htaccess` setting can impact the cursor behavior between two browsers.

Comment: Need more info. Does this effect users in Chrome on Windows, Mac, Linux? What versions of Chrome are effected? Any alerts or info from Console? The login prompt is generated by the browser when it encounters a specific HTTP Status code, so if after the login dialog is closed and the Cursor does not redraw, this is an issue in the browser that is not controlled by the HTML itself.

Comment: It affects Windows and Linux (I haven't tested Mac). Chrome versions 59 and 60 that I know of (unsure about older releases). I realize it's not the HTML - once you click another tab and come back, it works fine. No console alerts. I'm baffled!

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely a bug in Chrome, as the (maximally) stripped HTML produces the same problem:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
 <title>My .htaccess user/pass protected page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <input type="text">
 </body>
</html>
```

I've just filled out a bug report to Chrome. In mean time your users are probably best of to temporarily use another browser.